# Reading Outlook .msg file

Tags: java, email, outlook, apache-poi

I am trying to write code using Apache POI package to read Outlook .msg mail files

I am trying to get messageIds for all .msg files in a directory. However for some .msg files these messageId is null. After some observation I realized that these are the **reply messages (those messages with word "Reply" as the first word in their text body)**. For other To and From messages I am correctly getting message Ids. Why is this so?

**Code**

```
private String getMsgIds(String srcDir) throws IOException
{
    String cfile; //current files - temporary string to hold file name in for loop
    String msgIds = ""; //message Ids for all messages
    MAPIMessage msg = null; //temporary message variable to hold message while iterating        
    String msgId = "";

    File folder = new File(srcDir);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();


    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
    {

      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())  
      {           
          cfile = listOfFiles[i].getName();
          if (cfile.endsWith(".msg") || cfile.endsWith(".MSG"))
          {
              msg = new MAPIMessage(srcDir + "\\" + cfile);
          }
          try
          {
              Chunks chks = msg.getMainChunks();
              StringChunk strMsgId = chks.messageId;

              if(strMsgId != null)
              {
                  msgId = strMsgId.getValue();
                  msgIds += cfile+": "+msgId+"\n";
              }
              else
                  msgIds += cfile+": \n";
          }
          catch(NullPointerException e)
          {
              //ignore
          }

      }
    }

    return msgIds;
}
```

**Output**

```
12.msg: 
Brand ABC.msg: <093F1AED3DF94C4D878DBB625FC76805FFA809@xyz.abc.com>
RE  Test sent mail rule sent on behalf 1.msg: 
RE  Test sent mail rule sent on behalf 2.msg: 
Test mail to check sent rule on Ramprasad 2.msg: <2909CF96D97FDD43BC5EF34B2E2B8A317E5C3A@xyz.abc.com>
Test sent mail rule 1.msg: <B9EF3A9EC5BE2E4297FB08558016D9510F1B2A@xyz.abc.com>
Test sent mail rule 2.msg: <B9EF3A9EC5BE2E4297FB08558016D9510F1B3F@xyz.abc.com>
Test sent mail rule sent on behalf 1.msg:      <B9EF3A9EC5BE2E4297FB08558016D9510F1B51@xyz.abc.com>
Test sent mail rule sent on behalf 2.msg: <B9EF3A9EC5BE2E4297FB08558016D9510F1B6D@xyz.abc.com>
Test wth CC.msg: <EE6C216DE13B484EB4D860361A19C1D7D47905@xyz.abc.com>
test.msg: <EE6C216DE13B484EB4D860361A19C1D7D4780F@xyz.abc.com>
```

Notice above no messageId for 1st, 3rd and 4th message is objtained.
**Can I know if Reply messages do not MessageIds in their file? Or if Apache POI cannot read Message Ids from Reply messages?**

**Update**

I tried to grab the raw character stream using BufferedReader and InputStream. While observing character stream, it showed that these files dont have MessageId while others do have. So what may be the problem?

Comment: What version of Apache POI did you try with?

Comment: Apache POI v3.9, between see the update I made to question.